# Python forward message from Discord to Telegram

Tags: python, discord, telethon

I'm looking to create a script that forward message from discord to telegram. I made the example below but it's not working

```
client2 = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash, flood_sleep_threshold=3)
client2.connect()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client2.send_message("username", message=message.content)
```

Is there is any way to send a telegram message from another event.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you follow [Telethon's documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev) in order you should be able to get it to work. However "discord" events won't work with Telethon handlers (but you can just call `client.send_message`).

Comment: client is a Discord instance however client2 is a Telethon instance

Comment: That's fine. I put `client.` in my example because that's what Telethon's documentation uses.

Comment: I try it but it's not worked.

Comment: You will likely need to provide more information in order for us to provide meaningful answers.